# Does a hom-set of endomorphisms where they are all monomorphisms or epimorphisms form any common algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I'm trying to understand monomorphisms and epimorphisms more deeply, and was curious about their cancellative properties under post- and pre-composition (respectively) and how that property might relate to some types of algebras.

A set of endomorphisms forms a monoid under composition, and I am curious about what structure the subset of that restricted to only the morphisms that were monic might be. Since the only property afforded here is left-cancellation, I'm curious if a monoid imbued with this has any algebraic significance?

This small exploration has already been valuable to me in more clearly revealing how while left- or right-inverses imply left- or right-cancellation laws respectively, that cancellation laws do not imply inverses and are in fact more restrictive.

Thanks for any thoughts, I'm still pretty new to my studies of abstract algebra and category theory.

Comment: A category in which all morphisms are monic are called [left-cancellative categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/left+cancellative+category). One-object left-cancellative categories are precisely [left-cancellative monoids](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cancellative+monoid). There is no additional structure a priori, but these structures have been studied in their own right.